# Sums over primes in arithmetic progressions

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Do we know anything about sums over primes in arithmetic progressions like the following:
$$\sum_{\substack{q \equiv a (\text{mod } l) \\  q \le x}}  q^{\alpha}$$
where $q$ is a prime and $\alpha > 0$? If we consider the average over this sum:
$$ \frac{1}{\pi(x,l,a)} \sum_{\substack{q \equiv a (\text{mod } l) \\  q \le x}}  q^{\alpha}$$
where $\pi(x,l,a)$ is the number of primes $\le x$ in the residue class of $a$ modulo $l$, can we say that this average will be equal for all residue classes? Can we say anything of this sort even for specific values of $\alpha$?

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas Thanks for pointing that out. I meant to write $\pi(x,l,a)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard analytic proof of the prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions will work here as well, just replacing $L(s,\chi)$ with $L(s-\alpha,\chi)$; the asymptotic size of your first sum will be
$$
\frac{x^{1+\alpha}}{(1+\alpha)\phi(l)\log x}.
$$

Comment: Does this mean that asymptotically the "average" value should be equal across residue classes since the main term for $\pi(x,q,a)$ is also not dependent on $a$?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please refer to a specific proof of the PNT for arithmetic progressions that can be tweaked in the form you indicate? I tried without success.

Comment: If you know of a proof of PNT for arithmetic progressions that uses contour integration, almost surely that proof can be adapted to this scenario as well.